# Vue.js instance data missing when referencing vuex store

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, vuex

I'm attempting to use an api call to a django-rest backend to populate my data-store. The api-call appears to be working fine.

After loading `index.html` i can look at both `store_.state.products` and `v.$store.state.products` which both appear to have my json response from the API. You can see that here in the console after navigating to `index.html`:
[image: store_ object successfully is populated after the dispatch is run.]

and

[image: the v.$store reference confirms that store is populated after dispatch is run.]

However, `v.$data` as you can see appears to be empty.

[image: v.$data not populating]

Please find below my code.

**products.js**

```
//api get call
Vue.use(VueResource)

function get(url, request) {
    return Vue.http.get(url, request)
      .then((response) => Promise.resolve(response))
      .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error))
  }

//data store
const apiRoot = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product-list/?format=json'
const store_ = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        products: []
    },
    mutations: {
        'GET_PRODS': function (state, response) {
            state.products = response.body;
        },
        'API_FAIL': function (state, error) {
      console.error(error)
        },
    },
    actions: {
        getProducts (store) {
            return get(apiRoot)
        .then((response) => store.commit('GET_PRODS', response))
        .catch((error) => store.commit('API_FAIL', error))

        }
    }

})

//products component
Vue.component('product', {
    template: "#product-template",
    props: ['product'],
    delimiters: ["[[","]]"],
})

//root instance
const v = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store: store_,
    data : function () {
      return {
        //this works fine as expected with hardcoded objects fed as data
        //products : [
        //{
        //  id:1,
        //  name:'test',
        //  brief:'descrip',
        //},
        //{
        //  id:2,
        //  name:'other',
        //  brief:'something else',
        //}
        //]
        products : this.$store.state.products
            };
    },
    delimiters: ["[[","]]"],
})

//populate store.state.products with api-call
v.$store.dispatch('getProducts')
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/products/bootstrap.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/products/bootstrap-theme.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/products/base.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/products/index.css' %}" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static '/products/favicon.ico' %}"
      type="image/x-icon" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <template id="product-template">
    <div>
        <h1>[[ product.name ]]</h1>
        <h5>[[ product.brief ]]</h5>
    </div>
    </template>

    <div id="app">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row title-row">
          <h1 class="title">Products</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <product v-for="product in products"  :product="product" :key="product.id"></product>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{% static "products/vue.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "products/vue-resource.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "products/vuex.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "products/products.js" %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Potentially the products variable in **data** is initialised before the API has finished populating the store.

Try using a [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) value instead. Computed values are reactively updated as their dependencies change.

```
//root instance
const v = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store: store_,
    computed: {
        products: function () {
            return this.$store.state.products
        }
    },
    delimiters: ["[[","]]"],
})
```

However, you should use a getter to access the store to ensure that the property is properly reactive.

Comment: thanks for the reply! with computed i'm getting thrown instead the following errors: https://gist.github.com/mburke05/061d1810505d5ec85af8faa530282011

Comment: there's a whole bunch of the same two errors above, referenced at different lines in `vue.js` ; i think the "Property or method "product" is not defined" error is a template organizational error if I remember from skimming docs earlier but I honestly am not sure.